# Identifying a quadruply charged anion containing three carbon atoms

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions, identification

> This linear polyatomic ion containing three atoms of carbon has a negative four charge and is only found bonded with lithium and magnesium.

Could anyone identify this for me? It's from a quiz bowl clue that doesn't have the answer with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Sesquicarbide

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=li4c3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) suggests that $\ce{Li4C3}$ is a real compound, but based on what I saw in the links, it probably is not ionic in the same way that lithium acetylide $\ce{Li2C2}$ is.

$\ce{Mg2C3}$ appears to be the formula for [magnesium carbide](https://www.google.com/search?q=mg2c3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), or at least *a magnesium carbide*.

A [carbide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbide) is a binary compound of carbon and a less electronegative element, usually a metal or metalloid. Carbide is also a generic name for mono- and polyatomic anions containing only carbon. The following ions would all carbide ions: $\ce{C^{4-}, C2^2-, C2^{4-}, C2^{6-}, C3^{4-}, C3^{6-1}, C3^{8-}}$, etc.

The special name of [three of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbide#Salt-like_.28saline.29_carbides) carbide ions are:

- $\ce{C^{4-}}$ - Methide
- $\ce{C2^{2-}}$ - Acetylide
- $\ce{C3^{4-}}$ - Sesquicarbide

Comment: Lithium and magnesium sesquicarbides are in fact considered to be ionic.  See for example [here](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introchem/chapter/carbides/).